# How do I read /var/log/lastlog

Tags: linux, centos6

This is a 30GB file, I tried to open it in `VIM` 
It does not show anything, How can I see contents of this file

This is CentOS 6.5

Comment: Note that the lastlog file is probably not really 30 GB, because it is a sparse file. See NOTE in the man page of `lastlog(8)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Run the [`lastlog`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lastlog.8.html) command:

```
$ lastlog
```

Comment: how would I read a lastlog residing on an external harddisk, i.e. from another machine?